# Making An Overlar Appear On Button Tap In Corona SDK

Tags: user-interface, button, lua, coronasdk

I've created a popup overlay instead of the traditional composer.showOverlay in Corona SDK(Code Below). I'm adding three button to the overlay as shown below. However, only the first button endtered will appear. Any Suggestions?

```
--Overlay Executed Via Pause Button
    pausedPopup = function()

    local group = display.newGroup()
    local back = display.newRoundedRect( group, 0, 0, 200, 150, 12 )
    back:setFillColor( 255/255, 255/255, 255/255 )
    back.x = centerX
    back.y = centerY

    local messages = {}
    messages[#messages+1] = "PAUSED"

    local tmp = display.newText( group, messages[ math.random( 1, #messages )], 0, 0, gameFont,44 )
    tmp:setFillColor( 109/255, 182/255, 224/255 )
    tmp.x = back.x
    tmp.y = back.y -30


    local MenuLevels = widget.newButton({
        id = "MenuLevels",
        width = 100,
        height = 100,
         defaultFile = "MenuLevels.png",
        onEvent = handleMenuLevelsEvent
    })
    MenuLevels.x = centerX 
    MenuLevels.y = centerY +40
    sceneGroup:insert( MenuLevels )


    local MenuPlay = widget.newButton({
        id = "MenuPlay",
        width = 100,
        height = 100,
         defaultFile = "MenuPlay.png",
        onEvent = handleMenuPlayEvent
    })
    MenuPlay.x = centerX -90
    MenuPlay.y = centerY +40
    sceneGroup:insert( MenuPlay )

    local MenuReset = widget.newButton({
        id = "MenuReset",
        width = 100,
        height = 100,
         defaultFile = "MenuReset.png",
        onEvent = handleMenuResetEvent
    })
    MenuReset.x = centerX +90
    MenuReset.y = centerY +40
    sceneGroup:insert( MenuReset )


    transition.to( group, { alpha = 0, time = 1000, delay = 5500 } )
    timer.performWithDelay( 6600, function() group:removeSelf() end )
end
```

Comment: Are you using composer and have you checked out composer.showOverlay? Helps you organize the scenes a lot. https://docs.coronalabs.com/api/library/composer/showOverlay.html

Comment: You mean only show `MenuLevels` button when `pausedPopup` called?

Comment: I wish to show all three, but only MenuLevels is appearing at the moment.

Comment: I tried with no button pic, and all buttons showed, also the text "PAUSED" and the rect on the top (cover the buttons)

Comment: Do you mind sending me what you have(code wise) where you're able to display the buttons as text. I tried that as well, and I was still unable to see more than a single button. Here are photos of what I'm getting. [link](https://plus.google.com/b/118216460241086534391/photos/118216460241086534391/albums/6238917734608088401)

Comment: @W001W [Code here](https://github.com/SES-xuelan/code4stackoverflow/blob/master/34701319/main.lua)